# Use AddDays function in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datetime

Need some help finishing up this program, everything works and runs like I want it but I need to display an inputbox that allows the user to enter in the date they want for their invoice stored in service_date and then this date will display in the listbox with all the other items that I have put in there. I know I need to use the AddDays function but I have no clue on how to do it, and researching online has just led me to 100 other things that aren't that.

So here is my code:

```
 Dim Customer As String
Dim Phone As String
Dim Hours As Double
Dim Parts As Double
Dim due_date As String
Dim service_date As String

Private Sub cmdInputBox_Click()

    Dim service_date = InputBox("Enter the date of service. (MM/DD?YYYY)")
    MsgBox("That's your date, " & service_date.ToString)
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Private Sub CustInfo_Click()

    Customer = txtCustomer.Text
    Phone = mtbPhone.Text

    Double.TryParse(txtHours.Text, Hours)
    Double.TryParse(txtParts.Text, Parts)

    If Customer.Length < 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter customer information.")
    End If

    If Phone = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter phone number.")
    End If

    If Not Double.TryParse(txtHours.Text, Hours) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter labor hours.")
    End If

    If Not Double.TryParse(txtParts.Text, Parts) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter parts and supplies.")
    End If

    ''Perform calculations

    Dim Total_Cost As Double
    Dim Labor_Cost As Double
    Dim Parts_Cost As Double

    Parts_Cost = (Parts * 0.5 * 2)
    Labor_Cost = (Hours * 35)
    Total_Cost = (Hours + Parts)


    Customer = txtCustomer.Text
    Phone = mtbPhone.Text

    lstBill.Items.Clear()
    lstBill.Items.Add("Customer: " & vbTab & Customer.ToUpper)
    lstBill.Items.Add("Phone: " & vbTab & vbTab & Phone)
    lstBill.Items.Add("Service Date: " & vbTab & due_date)
    lstBill.Items.Add("Invoice Date: " & vbTab & service_date)
    lstBill.Items.Add("Labor Cost: " & vbTab & FormatCurrency(Labor_Cost))
    lstBill.Items.Add("Parts Cost: " & vbTab & FormatCurrency(Parts_Cost))
    lstBill.Items.Add("Total Cost: " & vbTab & FormatCurrency(Total_Cost))
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Private Sub btnBill_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBill.Click

    cmdInputBox_Click()

    CustInfo_Click()

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use the DateTimePicker?

Comment: Because the user has to enter it it in. I thought about putting that in the inputbox...would that work out in an input box? The user gets prompted when they click a button on the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim strDate As String = InputBox("Enter date?", , "")
If strDate = "" Then Exit Sub
Dim dteDate As Date
Dim enUS As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")
If Date.TryParseExact(strDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", enUS, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, dteDate) Then
  MsgBox("Date is " & dteDate.ToString)
End If
```

Comment: You're welcome. I'd appreciate you accepting my answer if it helped. Cheers, and happy programming!

Comment: What if the user enters the date as 10-5-2012 ?

Comment: There is an overload of the Date.TryParseExact method that allows you to use an array of possible date formats, if I remember correctly.